# How to open a web page in different div/frame using html?

Tags: html

i have a webpage which has 3 frames, and what i want to do is, while clicking button of frame 1, i want to open web page in frame 2 area.

is it possible? If yes then how to achieve that? and if no then can i do it with div?

**See Below Code**

```
<body>
    <a href="http:/www.google.com/" target="Demo">Click Me</a>
</body>
```

in Above code "Demo" is id of 'Frame'.

As per my understanding it "google.com" page should open in frame which has id "Demo" but here it is not happening.

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Google has some server-side code that stops other websites opening http://www.google.com/ in an iframe. It's to stop people doing it for malicious purposes. Change the URL to something different (http://www.example.com/) and see if it works.